# How to filter through column datatable which has more than one value in column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have datatable in my code where user_email column has values like

```
<td><label>ad@abc.com</label>
<label>ad2@abc.com</td></label>
```

and another column of hotels like

```
<td>
    <label>abd</label><br/>
    <label>bbd</label>
</td>
```

i want to add filter of each column but want to filter like single values i had define datatable like this

```
$('#example2').DataTable( {
    initComplete: function () {
        var i = 0;
        this.api().columns().every(function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value="0">All</option></select>')
                    .insertBefore('table')
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );
                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
        });
    }
} );
```

So guys can you suggest me how to do this.here is my demo:http://jsfiddle.net/qmzd0u5n/5/

Comment: Can you give 1-2 examples of search string and expected results?

Comment: In demo you can see hotel column has many field has many values like

Comment: In demo you can see hotel column has many field has many values like
Holiday Inn-Houma while in other Candlewood Suites,Radisson,Holiday Inn-Houma all are hotels in only one record so when filter is addedd i tshould be all hotels will be in seprate ooption of select. and result should if hotel is match in any row then it should be displayed